# Azure AD B2C missing email claim with local account and user id sign-in

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am setting up a new Azure AD B2C directory with standard sign-in user policy. I plan to have the user accounts created by an administrator so sign-up policy is not required. My issue is that I want to return the email address created for a user account however when I test the user flow the email address is the only claim that's missing. Is there are reason for this and a way around it?

**Test user account with email address populated.**
[image]

**IDP settings**
[image]

[image]

**User flow application claims settings**
[image]

**Claims return when testing user flow**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

B2C built-in user flow mainly collects the email addresses from 2 positions of the local account.

One is `otherMails` (Microsoft Grpah) / `Alternate email`(Azure Portal).

[image]

The other is the identity whose signInType is `emailAddress` (Microsoft Graph).

[image]

So if your local account is signed up with "User ID" option, there is no identity whose signInType is `emailAddress`. And if the `otherMails` (Microsoft Grpah) / `Alternate email` is also not set, there won't be any emails claim in the token.

Please update the properties I mentioned (`otherMails` / `Alternate email` or use email address to sign up / add an identity whose signInType is `emailAddress` using Microsoft Graph) to make them be included in the token.

Comment: thanks that worked. I am also interested in returning the user principal name ("test" in my screenshot above) so that I can pre-populate the login_hint property when re-authenticating the user. However this claim does not seem to exist which is strange. Do you know if it's possible to return the upn claim with above scenario?

Comment: @OjM I think it's impossible. See a similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63601519/aad-b2c-missing-upn-claim-in-access-token?answertab=votes#tab-top.